# Using a C++ reference in inline assembly with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly

I have a spin lock with the xchg instruction.  The C++ function takes in the resource to be locked.

Following is the code

```cs
void SpinLock::lock( u32& resource )
 { 
     __asm__ __volatile__
       (
            "mov     ebx, %0\n\t" 
"InUseLoop:\n\t"
            "mov     eax, 0x01\n\t"        /* 1=In Use*/
            "xchg    eax, [ebx]\n\t"
            "cmp     eax, 0x01\n\t"
            "je      InUseLoop\n\t"
            :"=r"(resource)
            :"r"(resource)
            :"eax","ebx"
        ); 
}

void SpinLock::unlock(u32& resource ) 
{ 
    __asm__ __volatile__
        (
                /* "mov DWORD PTR ds:[%0],0x00\n\t" */
                "mov ebx, %0\n\t"
                "mov DWORD PTR [ebx], 0x00\n\t"
                :"=r"(resource)
                :"r"(resource)
                : "ebx"               
        );      
}
```

This code is compiled with  `gcc`  4.5.2  `-masm=intel` on a 64 bit intel machine.

The  `objdump`  produces following assembly for the above functions .

```html
0000000000490968 <_ZN8SpinLock4lockERj>:
  490968:       55                      push   %rbp
  490969:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  49096c:       53                      push   %rbx
  49096d:       48 89 7d f0             mov    %rdi,-0x10(%rbp)
  490971:       48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  490975:       8b 10                   mov    (%rax),%edx
  490977:       89 d3                   mov    %edx,%ebx

0000000000490979 <InUseLoop>:
  490979:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  49097e:       67 87 03                addr32 xchg %eax,(%ebx)
  490981:       83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
  490984:       74 f3                   je     490979 <InUseLoop>
  490986:       48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  49098a:       89 10                   mov    %edx,(%rax)
  49098c:       5b                      pop    %rbx
  49098d:       c9                      leaveq
  49098e:       c3                      retq
  49098f:       90                      nop


0000000000490990 <_ZN8SpinLock6unlockERj>:
  490990:       55                      push   %rbp
  490991:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  490994:       53                      push   %rbx
  490995:       48 89 7d f0             mov    %rdi,-0x10(%rbp)
  490999:       48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  49099d:       8b 00                   mov    (%rax),%eax
  49099f:       89 d3                   mov    %edx,%ebx
  4909a1:       67 c7 03 00 00 00 00    addr32 movl $0x0,(%ebx)
  4909a8:       48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  4909ac:       89 10                   mov    %edx,(%rax)
  4909ae:       5b                      pop    %rbx
  4909af:       c9                      leaveq
  4909b0:       c3                      retq
  4909b1:       90                      nop
```

The code dumps core when executing the locking operation.

Is there something grossly wrong here ?

Regards,
-J

Comment: gdb gives you the ability to get the precise machine instruction which is faulting.

Comment: try `print $rip` to get current instruction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, why are you using truncated 32-bit addresses in your assembly code whereas the rest of the program is compiled to execute in 64-bit mode and operate with 64-bit addresses/pointers? I'm referring to `ebx`. Why is it not `rbx`?

Second, why are you trying to return a value from the assembly code with `"=r"(resource)`? Your functions change the in-memory value with `xchg    eax, [ebx]` and `mov DWORD PTR [ebx], 0x00` and return `void`. Remove `"=r"(resource)`.

Lastly, if you look closely at the disassembly of `SpinLock::lock()`, can't you see something odd about `ebx`?:

```
mov    %rdi,-0x10(%rbp)
mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
mov    (%rax),%edx
mov    %edx,%ebx
<InUseLoop>:
mov    $0x1,%eax
addr32 xchg %eax,(%ebx)
```

In this code, the `ebx` value, which is an address/pointer, does not come directly from the function's parameter (`rdi`), the parameter first gets dereferenced with `mov    (%rax),%edx`, but why? If you throw away all the confusing C++ reference stuff, technically, the function receives a pointer to `u32`, not a pointer to a pointer to `u32`, and thus needs no extra dereference anywhere.

The problem is here: `"r"(resource)`. It must be `"r"(&resource)`.

A small 32-bit test app demonstrates this problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void unlock1(unsigned& resource) 
{ 
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
        /* "mov DWORD PTR ds:[%0],0x00\n\t" */
        "movl %0, %%ebx\n\t"
        "movl $0, (%%ebx)\n\t"
        :
        :"r"(resource)
        :"ebx"               
    );      
}

void unlock2(unsigned& resource) 
{ 
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
        /* "mov DWORD PTR ds:[%0],0x00\n\t" */
        "movl %0, %%ebx\n\t"
        "movl $0, (%%ebx)\n\t"
        :
        :"r"(&resource)
        :"ebx"               
    );      
}

unsigned blah;

int main(void)
{
  blah = 3456789012u;
  cout << "before unlock2() blah=" << blah << endl;
  unlock2(blah);
  cout << "after unlock2() blah=" << blah << endl;

  blah = 3456789012u;
  cout << "before unlock1() blah=" << blah << endl;
  unlock1(blah); // may crash here, but if it doesn't, it won't change blah
  cout << "after unlock1() blah=" << blah << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
before unlock2() blah=3456789012
after unlock2() blah=0
before unlock1() blah=3456789012
Exiting due to signal SIGSEGV
General Protection Fault at eip=000015eb
eax=ce0a6a14 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One correction is for 64 bit the movl needs to be substituted by movq.